# Sencha: How do I add items to carousel using array

Tags: arrays, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an array created like this:
`var thecharts = new Array(chartg, chartb);`

In my view I have a carousel and the items of the carousel will be determined by the array `thecharts`
The code looks like this:

```
items: [
                {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                width: '90%',
                height: '70%',
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent:true,
                id: 'carousel'
            },

            items: [
                thecharts[0],
                thecharts[1]

            ]
        },
```

This works fine like this. However, the size of the array may change depending on other criteria. Therefore, I would rather not use the index and just drop the entire array into `items` and have it look like this:

```
items: [ thecharts ]
```

I tried it that way, but it just returned the first element in the array. How do I get it to return all elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
items: thecharts
```